# Is it bad practise to only log an exception when it is caught?

Tags: exception

Are there any negatives to catching an exception and just logging it? This is like the bare minimum done on every exception catch, but it doesn't really do anything about the exception.

I do believe this depends on the circumstances e.g. user-facing exception needs a popup etc. but something on the backend which the user doesn't see, does not. Or maybe there's more to it than just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, do the right thing in each given situation. Sometimes, that means just logging the exception. In other cases, you can perform specific, targeted recovery.

If a user has requested that you open a file, for example, and you catch a `FileNotFoundException`, it's appropriate to report this to the user and provide them the opportunity to select a different file. Or if parsing a user-provided string triggers a `FormatException` (though you'll often use a *TryX* pattern to avoid exceptions here), tell the user to enter a numeric string.

Often, the best thing to do is *not catch the exception at all*. If you can't do anything appropriate with it, let it bubble up to the root of your application stack, where you can log it, or often, just let it crash your application. If you don't know why you're seeing an exception, are you really sure your application is healthy, and won't corrupt data?

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions should only occur in exceptional circumstances, perhaps look at if your code can be rewritten to perform a check before doing whatever the operation is that is causing the exception to be thrown and log the result of the check if it fails.

You should be using the exceptions to track down bugs / inform the user that their input is incorrect / there was a glitch in the matrix

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to propagate exceptions up to the GUI level, where they can be caught. It is very frustrating to know that exceptions are caught along the way and you don't have a clue where they occurred (no stack trace).

When you are working within a framework, you sometimes cannot propagate the Exception because of interface restrictions. In that case, I'll catch the Exception and try to make sure that I provides the class and method where it occurred in the log message.

Answer (score 0):

Some exceptions indicate that things are failing very badly, and the application should shut down as quickly as practical to avoid corrupting the system; data may be safed to a recovery file, but should not overwrite the primary file.  Other exceptions indicate that an unexpected but recoverable situation has occurred.  Others indicate that Microsoft left out a Try___ method they should have included in the API (e.g. Control.TryBegininvoke).  In the former situation, eating an exception would be very bad.  In the last situation, eating an exception is the cleanest way to get working code (the workarounds necessary to ensure that Control.BeginInvoke won't throw are horrible, and are apt to cause more strife than swallowing exceptions from BeginInvoke).  In the middle situation, an exception handler should fix the situation so that the module containing it can obey its contracts.  If that can be done, there's no need to propagate the exception further.